# ggplot2 with side by side and proportional fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, fill

I have data that looks like this:
[image]

My goal is to have a barplot grid as follows: Each plot will be specific to 1 race_ethnicity group. The x-axis in each plot will be the different age_bin groups. For each age_bin, there will be two bars: 1 for men, and 1 for women. For each bar, I want it to be filled with the proportion of Likely/(Unlikely + Likely). Preferably, each bar would have a height of 1 and a line cut through it so Likely% of that bar is one color with a label. This is what I currently have:

[image]

I am running into issues with 1) using a predefined proportion as the fill, and 2) having two different "fills" (one for biological sex, one for the predefined proportion.

Thanks to anyone who can help with this. My code is currently the following:

```
ggplot(data=who_votes_data, aes(x=age_bin,y=1, fill=gender)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',aes(fill = gender), position = position_dodge2()) +
  facet_wrap(~race_ethnicity, nrow = 2, scales = "free") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", prop*100),"%"), y=prop), 
            colour="white") +
  labs(x = expression("Age Group"), y= ("Prortion of Likely Voters"),
       title = "Proportion of Likely Voters Across Age Groups, Race/Ethnicity, and Sex",
       caption="Figure 1") + theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.5, size = 18))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a7433iwXNSwcuXDJOvqsxNDN6oaYULVlyw22E41JROU/edit?usp=sharing

Updated Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
df<- read.csv("samplevotes.csv")

df %>% 
group_by(race_ethnicity, age_bin, gender) %>% 
summarise(Likely = sum(Likely), 
          Unlikely = sum(Unlikely), 
          proportion = Likely/(Likely+Unlikely)) %>% ungroup() %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = age_bin, y = proportion, fill = gender)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
facet_wrap(~race_ethnicity, nrow = 2) + 
geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", proportion*100),"%"), y=proportion), position = position_dodge(width = 1),  colour="Black", size = 2.2) + 
labs(x = expression("Age Group"), y= ("Proportion of Likely Voters"), title = "Proportion of Likely Voters Across Age Groups, Race/Ethnicity, and Sex", caption="Figure 1") +
 theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.5, size = 18))
```

[image]

Comment: You need to make `likely` and `Nonlikely` one column with `pivot_longer`.  Also please provide some data.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! I've appended a link with some data - can you elaborate more on using pivot_longer? EDIT: nvm documentation was quite clear. Do you have any advice for creating the plot with this new arrangement?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I would use. I did make some changes based on the way the data was combined.

```
df %>% 
group_by(race_ethnicity, age_bin, gender) %>% 
summarise(Likely = sum(Likely), 
          Unlikely = sum(Unlikely), 
          proportion = Likely/(Likely+Unlikely)) %>% ungroup() %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = age_bin, y = proportion, fill = gender)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
facet_wrap(~race_ethnicity, nrow = 2) + 
geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", proportion*100),"%"), y=proportion), position = position_dodge(width = 1),  colour="Black", size = 2.2) + 
labs(x = expression("Age Group"), y= ("Proportion of Likely Voters"), title = "Proportion of Likely Voters Across Age Groups, Race/Ethnicity, and Sex", caption="Figure 1") +
 theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.5, size = 18))
```

Here is what it looks like
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Quick question - did you do any other preprocessing outside of loading in the dataframe? I'm assuming you never used pivot_longer since the Likely column is intact, but this causes the following error when I run it: Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `race_ethnicity`. * Plot is missing `race_ethnicity` * Layer 1 is missing `race_ethnicity` * Layer 2 is missing `race_ethnicity`

Comment: I used `library(tidyverse)`. Did you ?

Comment: Yes! I think %>% fails without it so I had that from the start. I'm using ggplot2 and R.4.0.2

Comment: did you `ungroup()`

Comment: Yes - I have added the updated code chunk to the end of the main body of the question above if that helps!

Comment: could you share the `glimpse(df)`

Comment: Updated the question with a picture!

Comment: maybe a character reading issue. type in `race_ethnicity` everywhere from the `str`. See if that works. Also run this row-by-row (without the plus sign) and see what errors arise at all parts. Here is what I am thinking: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2517

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by character reading issue - do you mean in the title? And I get an error immediately with ggplot saying age_bin not found (perhaps this has to do with ungroup()) on the ggplot line. To be clear, I ran everything from "df %>% group_by" to "ggplot(aes(x = age_bin, y = proportion, fill = gender))"

Comment: what about just through the `ungroup()` share that `str`

Comment: It's a 1 row dataframe with Likely, Unlikely, and proportion as columns.

Comment: Something is wrong with the `group_by %>% summarise`